# Average function excluding value for each row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a simple way to calculate the average for each column in a pandas DataFrame and for each row *exclude* the specific value? The `x` in each row below marks the value in each iteration to be excluded from the calculation:

```
    a    b                     a    b                    a    b
0   1    2                 0   x    x                0   1    2
1   2    4    first loop   1   2    4   second loop  1   x    x   etc.
2   3    6       --->      2   3    6     --->       2   3    6   --->
3   4    8                 3   4    8                3   4    8
4   5   10                 4   5   10                4   5   10
                           ____________              _____________
                   col_avg:  3.5  7.0        col_avg: 3.25  6.5

Using only 4 values at each iteration, as the "x" is excluded from data set
```

resulting in a new DataFrame

```
    a_x    b_x
0   3.5    7.0
1   3.25   6.5
2   3.0    6.0
3   2.75   5.5
4   2.5    5.0
```

Thanks

/N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start off with the first step, let's say we were interested in summing instead of calculating the average values. In that case, we would be adding all elems along each col except the current elem. Other way to look at it/solve it would be to sum all elems along each col and subtract the current elem itself. So, essentially we could get the sum for all columns with `df.sum(0)` and simply subtract `df` from it, keeping the axis 
aligned. [`Broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) would take care of performing these operations across all cols in one go.

To get the second step of averaging, we simply divide by the number of elems involved for each col's summing, i.e. `df.shape[0]-1`.

Thus, we would have a vectorized solution, like so -

```
df_out = (df.sum(0) - df)/float(df.shape[0]-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [128]: df
Out[128]: 
   a   b
0  1   2
1  2   4
2  3   6
3  4   8
4  5  10

In [129]: (df.sum(0) - df)/float(df.shape[0]-1)
Out[129]: 
      a    b
0  3.50  7.0
1  3.25  6.5
2  3.00  6.0
3  2.75  5.5
4  2.50  5.0
```

To set the column names to the desired ones, do : `df_out.columns = ['a_x','b_x']`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!
As the data contains NaN-values, the "true" average will need to be calculated using df.count() instead of df_shape[0], as otherwise I would count the NaN's as actual values. I didn't specify that in the question however, but just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, but needed both the mean and the standard deviation, excluding the current row

Standard deviation was quite a bit harder to calculate due to needing all of the values *and* the mean of the groups

The following can be easily extended to pretty much any of the aggregating functions from numpy

```
In [266]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(5) + 1, "b": 2 * (np.arange(5) + 1)})

In [267]: df
Out[267]:
   a   b
0  1   2
1  2   4
2  3   6
3  4   8
4  5  10

In [268]: import numpy.ma as ma
     ...: import numpy as np
```

Create a 3-dimensional numpy array by stacking the DataFrame's values for as many rows as there are

```
In [269]: t = np.stack(tuple(df.values for _ in range(len(df.index))), axis=0)

In [270]: t
Out[270]:
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6],
        [ 4,  8],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6],
        [ 4,  8],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6],
        [ 4,  8],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6],
        [ 4,  8],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6],
        [ 4,  8],
        [ 5, 10]]])
```

Create a set of stacked identity matrices to use as a mask (i.e. exclude the current row) in the aggregating function

```
In [271]: e = np.stack(tuple(np.eye(len(df.index)) for _ in range(len(df.columns))), axis=2)

In [272]: e
Out[272]:
array([[[1., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]])
```

Construct a masked array (numpy.ma.array) from the stacked data and identities

```
In [275]: masked_array = ma.array(t, mask=e)

In [276]: masked_array
Out[276]:
masked_array(
  data=[[[--, --],
         [2, 4],
         [3, 6],
         [4, 8],
         [5, 10]],

        [[1, 2],
         [--, --],
         [3, 6],
         [4, 8],
         [5, 10]],

        [[1, 2],
         [2, 4],
         [--, --],
         [4, 8],
         [5, 10]],

        [[1, 2],
         [2, 4],
         [3, 6],
         [--, --],
         [5, 10]],

        [[1, 2],
         [2, 4],
         [3, 6],
         [4, 8],
         [--, --]]],
  mask=[[[ True,  True],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]],

        [[False, False],
         [ True,  True],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]],

        [[False, False],
         [False, False],
         [ True,  True],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]],

        [[False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [ True,  True],
         [False, False]],

        [[False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [ True,  True]]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

And finally calculate your aggregate values

```
In [277]: np.nanmean(masked_array, axis=1).data
Out[277]:
array([[3.5 , 7.  ],
       [3.25, 6.5 ],
       [3.  , 6.  ],
       [2.75, 5.5 ],
       [2.5 , 5.  ]])

In [278]: np.nanstd(masked_array, axis=1).data
Out[278]:
array([[1.11803399, 2.23606798],
       [1.47901995, 2.95803989],
       [1.58113883, 3.16227766],
       [1.47901995, 2.95803989],
       [1.11803399, 2.23606798]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `pd.concat()` and `drop()`

```
pd.concat([df.drop(r).mean() for r in df.index],keys=df.index).unstack()
```

or

```
pd.concat([df.drop(r).mean() for r in df.index],axis=1).T
```

or

```
df.apply(lambda x: [np.roll(x,-i)[1:].mean() for i in range(df.shape[0])])
```

Output:

```
      a    b
0  3.50  7.0
1  3.25  6.5
2  3.00  6.0
3  2.75  5.5
4  2.50  5.0
```